# upsell.phtml - get products without column and row sorting

Tags: upselling

the upsell.phtml is built a little bit dated imho. It loads rows and then products for each row. I'd like to load every product without a table.

Something like

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getProductCount();$_i++): ?>
        <!-- DOM for Upsell Product -->
    <?php endfor; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
      <div class="box-collateral box-up-sell">
         <h2><?php echo $this->__('You may also be interested in the following  product(s)') ?></h2>
         <ul class="product-small-view products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col" id="upsell-product-table">
            <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemCollection()->getItems() as $_link): ?>
              <li class="item">
                 <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(220,176) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" />
                 </a>
                 <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-info">
                      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                      <?php echo '<span class="manufacturer_logo" ><img src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN) . 'frontend/atlas/responsive/images/marcas/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $_link->getAttributeText('marca')) . '.png' . '" style="width:48px;" title="' . $_link->getAttributeText('marca') . '"></span>' ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="product-price pull-both">
                      <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link) ?>
            </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is a working code. Check it